# How to determine which code in a project/solution is the most often used?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, integration-testing

If I have an existing solution containing multiple c# projects, are there any static analysis tools that can help me determine which areas of code are the most often used?

I'd like to use this information in order to determine which areas should have their test coverage ramped up first.

I've looked at some static analysis tools already, but they mostly seem to focus on things like complexity, coding conventions, code duplication etc.

Alternatively, if there aren't any analysis tools available that can do this, do you have any advice about how to determine which code I ought to focus on testing first?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, what I'm looking for isn't code coverage. I'd like a rundown of which parts of my application are most often used, so that I can in turn focus on improving the coverage in those areas. I'm trying to avoid just writing tests for areas that don't yet have any, as they may be edge cases that aren't often executed.

Comment: In reply to your edit, are you certain that the proposed code coverage tools do not do profiling at the same time? When obtained though instrumentation, it is as easy to provide profiling information as it is to provide coverage information, so these tools may do both. Just saying, I am not familiar with them...

Comment: In my opinion the number of times a certain method is referenced is not related to the criticality of an error in that method. If a method is referenced and called only once e.g. during start-up an erroneous execution of that method might crash your application whereas a buggy method called a 1000 times might still leave your system in a stable state.

Comment: @Pascal: (Hi!)  We provide test coverage and profiling tools seperately, althought the instrumentation is pretty similar as you have observed, at least for execution-counts.  The display requirements are considerably different (see my answer and check out the display examples) and the overhead of the profile is higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even static analysis tools which do try to figure out what happens at run-time do not usually try to estimate how often a piece of code is executed. The subject is hard enough as it is!

But *dynamic analysis* tools (e.g. *profiling* tools that either rely on transparent instrumentation of the code or use sampling) can tell you, after one or several "typical" executions (you provide the entries that you judge typical), how often this or that function was executed.

See [Profiling (computer programming) on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question right, you are looking for a profiler. Give [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler) a try. It's free.

It's originally intended to profile an application before shipping (to detect bottlenecks by measuring execution time of methods etc.) so I'm not sure if it's suitable for an application in a productive environment. At least it changes your code for profiling purposes and that might be unwanted. You should check this out.

Comment: This was my first thought, too. A profiler will tell you the number of times (relatively) a function is invoked as well as the amount of time spent in each function.

Answer (score 1):

[Code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) appears to be what you want.

[NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) is a popular code coverage tool for .NET, if you can afford it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see just *what* is used:
[SD C# Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage.html)

If you want to see *how often* it is used:
[SD C# Profiler Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/CSharpProfiler.html)

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is simply impossible to do accurately. The number of times something is executed can and usually will depend on the data that's entered at run-time. The best you can hope for from a static analysis tool is

1. a direct answer when statically determined
2. An O(N) style analysis otherwise

Even the latter would be quite difficult to get right overall. For example, it would need to know the complexity of essentially every function in the (huge and ever-expanding) .NET library. Some of those are hard to even characterize.

Just for example, how long does it take to allocate a block of memory? Well, usually it's usually nearly constant time -- but it's always possible that an allocation can trigger a garbage collection cycle, in which case the time taken will be (roughly) proportional to the number of objects still in use that were allocated since the last GC cycle...

Answer (score 1):

"Profiler" is what you're looking for; which you choose is up to you.

I've used HP's Diagnostic Server to do this, although it'd cost money.  It'll tell me what methods are called how many times, and the average and worst-case time spent in them.

As an important safety tip, running a profiler will slow down the execution of your code; it's not ideal for a long-term installation into a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If coverage is not what you look for then you could look use two things:

1. As suggested a profiler and run predictive test scenarios.
2. Use performance counters which would end in a more permanent solution. These are quite difficult to implement but are helpful to diagnose performance deltas by analyzing the counters report. One way to implement them would be to wrap boundaries and manage counters from those wrap. Be wary that it's way much easier to integrate in a new project than in an existing one.